# Dynamic Columns .withColumn Python DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I wanted to apply .`withColumn` dynamically on my Spark DataFrame with column names in `list`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

def get_dtype(dataframe,colname):
    return [dtype for name, dtype in dataframe.dtypes if name == colname][0] 
def get_matches(dataframe):
  return [x for x in dataframe.columns if get_dtype(dataframe,x)=='tinyint']

matches = get_matches(srcpartyaddressDF)
matches
```

Above code give me list of columns where column datatype is '`tinyint`'

**Result**:

```
Out[67]: ['verified_flag', 'standard_flag', 'overseas_flag', 'active']
```

Now I want to do below for each column from list `matches` dynamically

```
partyaddressDF = srcpartyaddressDF.withColumn("verified_flag", col("verified_flag").cast(BooleanType())).withColumn("standard_flag", col("standard_flag").cast(BooleanType())).withColumn("overseas_flag", col("overseas_flag").cast(BooleanType())).withColumn("active", col("active").cast(BooleanType()))
```

How can this be acheived in Python3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```py
# import is necessary only for python 3
from functools import reduce

def do_cast(df, cl):
    return df.withColumn(cl, col(cl).cast(BooleanType()))

matches = ['verified_flag', 'standard_flag', 'overseas_flag', 'active']
partyaddressDF = reduce(do_cast, matches, srcpartyaddressDF)
```

basically, it takes initial value (`srcpartyaddressDF`), and apply first item from list (column name), then takes 2nd value from list, and use it with result that was obtained on first execution, then 3rd value, ...